# Is it possible to determine the value of the following function?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be a pair of generic sequences, and let $L$ be a constant. Consider the following function:

$$f(x):=a_o+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left({a_n}\cos{\frac{n\pi x}{L}+b_n\sin{\frac{n\pi x}{L}}}\right)$$

I'm currently discussing with another person whether this function, as it is right now and with no extra information, is actually solvable, that is, if you can determine a value for $f(x)$ for each $x$, or at least, for a certain domain, that is not in terms of $n$. The sequences and the constant are not defined.

It seems to me like this is a generic form of the function, while the other person argues that there exists an actual solution for each value of $x$. Any opinions?

**EDIT**: Clarification: The question is, given a value of $x$, ¿is it possible to determine a concrete value for $f(x)$?

Comment: The question is, given a value of $x$, ¿is it possible to determine a concrete value for $f(x)$?

Comment: You mean whether the series converges independently of the assumptions on $a_n, b_n$? No.